# Can my website have an image and no date in its Google SERP?

Tags: google, google-search, search-results

The majority of the traffic to the website I am working on is organic. I was assigned to make updates so that our SERP shows an image to increase the click-through rate on our #1 result.

Unfortunately, the image seems to be tied with a 2005 date. Whenever we get the image to show, it shows this 2005 date (which is when Google first crawled the page), and the date goes away when the image is gone. I've attempted to change the date picked up by Google, since the page was updated many times since 2005, but with no luck (the "new" date will only show when the image does not).

I was wondering if there was some way of showing an image without showing a date. The content in this particular page is for a definition that does not change often (maybe once every few years), and so it would be better to have no date at all, although changing the date itself to a 2014 date would be nice as well (the page was recently updated).

Edit: previous image vs image used vs logo:

[image: Company image logo example]

This was the first image that was used. It was made in NOV 2013, and was meant to be used to appear in social media (using the og:image tag). When this image appeared, the Google SERP showed a 2005 date. Refer to this as IMAGE_1.

[image: Company og:image example]

This was the second image that was used. The first image appeared cropped on our SERP, and we had hoped that the 2005 date was associated with the first image. This image appeared just how we wanted it; however, the 2005 date still appeared on the SERP. This image was created in 2014. Refer to this as IMAGE_2.

[image: Company logo example]

This is our company logo. IMAGE_2 is basically this image with added white-space so that it would work for the 200x200 requirements for Facebook, and so that it would display properly in the SERP. I do not know when this image was created. Refer to this as IMAGE_3.

Answer (score 1):

The date you're seeing might be contained within the EXIF information for that image (most people are unaware of this). It's been confirmed for sometime that Google uses the [exchangeable image file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) (EXIF) information stored in digital images in its Image Search and for Google+, as can be seen [here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/07/google-image-search-shows-more.html) and [here](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1304987?hl=en).

You can view the EXIF information for images using various [online EXIF viewer sites](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=online%20exif%20viewer). Using an EXIF editor application, you can also change the date fields for your image to 2014.

You should also check to see if the image is cached within Google's Image Search by uploading your image to [Google Image Search](http://www.google.com/imghp) (click on the camera icon). If the image is found, you can ask Google to remove it by following the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181721?hl=en), or the second option [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/troubleshooter/3425345?hl=en#ts=3502652). This may also help to clear the date associated with that image.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case. The image itself was created for this purpose (i.e. to show up in the Google SERP), and it has a 2014 date attached to it according to http://exif-viewer.com/. Since the image was created in 2014, it also does not have an older version of itself cached (I made sure to give it a unique name).

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question. Maybe you can clarify this: `Whenever we get the image to show, it shows this 2005 date`. Where exactly is it showing this date - can you provide a URL to show this? Also, you should be aware that Google uses image recognition during it's indexing, so just renaming a file wouldn't impact that.

Comment: Do you by chance know if the image recognition that Google uses for indexing would match similar images (for example, creating an image that is essentially our company logo in a 200x200 size)? Could this be the issue?

Also, in regards to the image showing, we removed it from the page, and have attempted different variations of the image to see if we can get the date to disappear. That is what I meant by "Whenever we get the image to show...".

Comment: You mean matching similar images of different sizes? What would really help clarify your question is to provide a URL to show what you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply--I was away for the weekend. I've added three example images that look similar to the images we use. In regards to the images, IMAGE_1 was not made from a previously-existing image on the website. It is, however, used as our facebook profile picture. Does this clarify things a bit, or do you need anything else?

Comment: We'd need the URL to the search results where you're seeing the 2005 date reported.

Comment: Having a look at it...can you tell me where the "2005" was being displayed?

Comment: The 2005 date was being displayed in the place where the current date is. The current date has been placed by having it appear in the article after "updated at", when attempting to have it replace the previous one (although it won't do so when an image is present).

Comment: You mean in the snippet's description in Google's search results page, it had "2005" instead of "Nov 18, 2013 - A 529 Plan..."?

Comment: Yes. The 2005 date is most likely being pulled from when Google first crawled the page, and is actually not in the text of the page itself. Would it be better to move this conversation to chat?

Comment: Yep, not in the text, checking for cached versions of the page...I think you did the right thing by adding the "Updated: 2013-11-18", but the meta "last-modified" tag shouldn't really affect anything. Here's the meta tags it understands:  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812

Comment: The earliest version I can find cached was from [2008](http://web.archive.org/web/20080615130306/http://www.savingforcollege.com/intro_to_529s/what-is-a-529-plan.php), and looks very similar aside from the video. It seems Google couldn't recognize the page had been updated based on earlier indexes. However, now that you added the "Updated: 2013-11-18", I don't think you should be having any issues with the 2005 date appearing again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12695/discussion-between-user3191820-and-dan)

Comment: I don't have anything more to add - you seem to have already fixed the problem by updating the content as one would normally do.

Comment: I apologize if my question was not clear. The issue I am having isn't to get rid of the date. I am trying to have the image up, but have a non-2005 date show. With what you currently saw in the HTML, adding an og:image meta-tag will get the image to show, and will also add a 2005 date (even with the updated-at 2013 date present).

Comment: The logo in your source `img src="/graphics/header_logo.gif"` is being displayed just fine and so is the date. I don't see how adding Metadata like `og:image` would change that for Google, nor is this even currently visible, and it's also very unclear from your question. Questions here shouldn't [only apply to your site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), therefore I don't think others can learn from this question, so I'm going to have to close it.